# Explanation of strange error in c

Tags: c

Just as I compiled:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

main() 
{ 
print("hello\cworld"); 
}
```

I got this error/output:

> warning:unknown escape sequence '\c'
>
> C:\Users\Abc\Appdata\Local\Temp/ccQLcaaa.o(.txt+ox32):abc.c:undefined
>   reference to 'print'
>
> ld returned 1 exit status.

Can anyone of you deduce this error and tell me,in some words,what the compiler wants to say(especially "`undefined reference`" one)

Comment: Please turn in your compiler's warnings! `-Wall -Werror`, and adding `-std=c99` is a good idea too.

Comment: Is it a `printf` ? Change `print` to `printf`

Answer (score 9):

> undefined reference to 'print'

`print` is not a function declared in `stdio.h`.  Surely you meant `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

The messages you cite start with reference to "\c". This is called "escape sequence", because it should have some special meaning. However, "\c" is not known, like "\n" which means linefeed, "\r" (carriage return"), "\t" (tab) or others.

This is the "warning" you get, as soon as the compiler parses hello-world string. Later on it complains about `print` what others pointed out already.

Answer (score 1):

The **compiler** creates the object code files from the source code.

The **linker** creates the executable that can be ran.

If you receive a *linker error*, it means that your code **compiled** OK, but some functions or libraries that is needed cannot be found. In your case the linker prevent the executable to be created since `print` is not a standard function that's part of `stdio.h`, so it can't find a *reference* to it, exactly like it says. As others told you, you probably want to [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and not to `print` Turning compiler's error on should really help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the string `hello\cworld` *without warning* then you'll have to do the following

```
printf("hello\\cworld");
```

Else, if you were trying to figure out whether `\c` would do anything special, then it does not. The compiler encounters a `\` and thinks that the next character will have a special meaning and hence performs that way. It works for `\n` , `\r` and so on, but when the compiler sees `\c` he tries to tell you that either you have written `\c` by mistake, and hence warns you.